# SSIS ODATA Connection issue

Tags: ssis, odata, sharepoint-2013, sql-server-data-tools

I am able to get into SharePoint site using browser but not able to connect it using SSIS ODATA Connector. I have admin rights in that site. We have multiple imports successfully running using same SharePoint Server right now. Using SSDT2012. I tried another site successfully to confirm I don't have issue with SSDT. Any idea what I am missing.
Error msg:

### TITLE: OData Connection Manager Editor

Test connection failed

---

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized. (System)

---

The logon attempt failed (System)

---

BUTTONS:

### OK

Answer (score 0):

What is the Service Document Location URL, you are giving in your case?  Here is mine which works well.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am aware of using "_vti_bin/listdata.svc" for sharepoint link. As I have said earlier, we have multiple imports running successfully. This particular one is giving an issue. Trying to figure out if anyone has experience in setting up security in Sharepoint site to allow SSIS to read data.

Comment: "This particular one is giving an issue".  Whats so special about it? Can you share more details on this one.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using basic authentication or Windows authentication?

If the former, double and triple-check that your userid and password are correct, and that the credentials have the proper access.

If the latter, check to see what user the package is running as.  Also, I've found that when using Windows Authentication, you have to go back and double check what the Basic Authentication settings are, and zero them out before going back to Windows Authentication.  It sounds crazy, but sometimes it works.